# Tkinter Scale for time labels

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to use the Tkinter scale feature to display a range of time. How can I edit the interval to display time in minutes? Or possibly convert the interval into time

```
# Time scale
    self.timeScale = tk.Scale(self.timeFrame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=630, from_=0, to=24, tickinterval=1,
                              showvalue=True)
    self.timeScale.grid(row=3, column=0)
```

Comment: every hour has 60 minutes so 24h has `24*60 = 1440` so you may need `to=1440` but it will display values 0... 1440. OR you would have to build own Scale from scratch. You can also try to find in Google - maybe someone already create scale for time.

Comment: you can also try `resolution=24/1440` but it will display `12:30` as `12.5`